# Change "offsetParent" of element to get position relative to it's closest parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use Jquery "draggable" & "droppable" to move elements from one div to another.

When i drop the elements into "droppable" i'd like to store the new position.
I can do this with: `$('draggedElement').position()`
Only problem is that i will get the position relative to the "offsetparent" wich is "body".
I'd like it to be relative to the dropzone.

Is it posible to change "offsetparent", or do i need to calculate the position somehow?

Jquery offsetparent(); accepts no arguments.

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/0apuqnxd/4/

Comment: Post some code on what you have please..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it's alot of code, but i can show an example...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Fiddle is up!

Comment: As per my analysis, you cannot just get its current `position` as on `UI`, because when you drop, the `element`, from `DOM`, will not move from the place where it was, but only `CSS` changes, w.r.t to `html`, and hence you are getting the normal `position` values, So you would need to calculate the position with some maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for offsetParent (https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/) says the following:

> Description: Get the closest ancestor element that is positioned.

You need to apply a position definition to the parent you are trying to offset against.

```
<div id="parent" style="position: relative;">
   <div id="draggedElement"></div>
</div>
```

Update:

Now you've provided a fiddle we can see that your draggable elements aren't children of the elements your dropping them into. So you have to do some maths to calculate the position. In pseudo code:

```
droppedPosition - (elementDroppedInto - draggableParent)
```

Comment: I do not understand. Check out my updated Fiddle. I set the div with class"flakUp" to position "relative". But console log don't show anything other the position relative to the body?!

Comment: Okay your draggable elements aren't children of what you're trying to get the offsetPosition against.

https://jsfiddle.net/0apuqnxd/4/

If you look at this updated fiddle, I've moved them into the second droppable area, and now your position is returning accurate to the position inside of that div.

Comment: If it has to work this way, you will have to do some maths. Calculate the difference between the offset position of the div you've dropped the element into, compared to it's parent and take that away from the position of the element you've dropped. [ droppedElementPosition - (droppedElementParentPosition - parentPosition) ]